# Relationship Anytime Health Q&A - Physical Fitness?

Tags: discussion

While doing some research for a client meeting, I came across http://www.anytimehealth.com/questions

Looks like SE has licensed its Q&A model to Anytime Fitness

What is the relationship between this site and the Anytime Fitness one? Perhaps there is a mutual benefit of a merge?

The Anytime Fitness site is clearly commercial. 
I can't see how many questions they have or if they have support for meta forums etc.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell there's no official affiliation with Anytime Fitness. People are free to use a format similar to SE (like OSQA, http://www.osqa.net/).

Furthermore, they seem to roll their own version, which lacks a lot of the features SE has. That makes merging all but impossible, even if it was something the communities wanted.